# Paid hotel as condition for getting visa?

Tags: visas, bookings, hotels

How to pay hotel on booking.com in case its "free cancellation" and they don't give option to pay in advance in credit card? I need prove of hotel payment as a condition for getting Visa for Bosnia.

Comment: Contact a hotel. They may accept paypal and provide you with an invitation letter stating you've paid for an accommodation.

Answer (score 2):

As you note, applicants for a visa for Bosnia and Herzegovina may be required to include confirmation of paid accommodation, or a signed and stamped voucher from a travel agency documenting payment.  While you may use Booking.com for your reservations, you would need to visit the hotel's website and make direct contact to arrange prepayment. At the same time, you might ask about its cancellation policy in the event a visa is not issued.

The [Bosnia and Herzegovina Embassy in Australia](http://www.bihembassy.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8&Itemid=129&lang=bs) also includes this useful information, that:

- those who stay in the territory longer than three days must register residence;
- those providing accommodation (hotels, motels, lodgings, camps etc.) must inform the authorities about foreigners registered;
- those places of accommodation may not confiscate and keep travel documents of foreigners;
- the foreigner should ask for a certificate on registration of residence, or bill on paid services;
- the foreigner must have evidence of registration of residence and to present this when leaving B&H, upon request of a border police officer.

Comment: I have been to Bosnia probably 20 times and I've never been asked for evidence of registration of residence on leaving.  In fact, I did not have it, because I was not registered -- I stayed in a private residence and never bothered with the police.  I don't need a visa to visit, however, and people who do need them might be treated differently.  I doubt it, though.